# Java crash on Ubuntu linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jvm, java-native-interface

Suddenly from one day to the next, with no apparent software or configuration changes we are starting to get JVM crashes with the following in the syslog:

```
 *** Error in `java': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f70344753d0 ***
 ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f7051ca17e5]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f7051caa37a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f7051cae53c]
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so(Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_disposeNativeScaler+0x64)[0x7f7028cd6154]
 [0x7f7039017e07]
```

As far as I can gather from similar issues this is caused by an error in a native library - in this case probably libfontmanager.so.

How can this be diagnosed further? Can I get a java-stacktrace of the situation causing this problem? In case this is a concurrency issue, it could perhaps be fixed on the java-side of things.

Using OpenJDK 1.8.0_181 on Ubuntu 16.04.5. I am unable to find a newer java build in Ubuntu repositories - maybe I overlooked it?

This is a production environment, so upgrade of major java version etc. would not be easy.

Comment: Are you using JNI in your app?

Comment: Also, are you using any kind of logging to file in your app?

Comment: No JNI is used in the application, but plenty of file logging.

Comment: This looks like a JDK bug. OpenJDK 1.8.0_181 appears to be the latest available at https://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/source/xenial/openjdk-8

Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: The above is the full backtrace. I wish I knew how to get a stacktrace of this fault/situation.

Comment: If you are not religious about openjdk, you could try switching to Oracle Hotspot. Never had issues with it. Is that an option?

Comment: @GergelyBacso it is possible, but a bit annoying as we prefer installing packages, and managing software with apt. Likewise a more recent build of OpenJDK8 could be tried.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was possibly caused by pdfbox version 1.8 (or actually possibly more likely fontbox version 1.8). After upgrading both to version 2.0, the problem looks like it might have gone away.

However several things were tried in a frenzy, to try to get rid of this problem, so this is not known for certain. Also the issue was intermittent, and might possibly not have been solved, even though it looks like it until now.